# Whats the best tutorial / place for learning generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a team of junior developers and they want to have better understanding and usages of generics.  Anyone recommend good tutorial or articles samples that are good places to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few links:

- [An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(vs.80).aspx)
- [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(VS.80).aspx)

Recommended books:

- [Professional .NET 2.0 Generics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764559885)
- [C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988363)

Answer (score 0):

[Bill Wagner's](http://srtsolutions.com/blogs/billwagner/default.aspx) [More Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321485890) has some really good content on Generics.